# Remove white space from text file with line breaks

Tags: php

I have a large file with line breaks and spaces. The file has text like as follows

```
Ampex 

Baofeng 

JBL 

Pioneer 

Sony 

1 BY ONE
```

To read the file i wrote this

```
$array = explode("\n", file_get_contents('brands.txt'));

foreach($array as $line) {
    
    $html_code = '<div class="form-check">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios1" value="option1" checked>
  <label class="form-check-label d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center" for="exampleRadios1">'.
     $line
    .'<span class="badge bg-primary rounded-pill">1</span>
  </label>
</div>';
echo $html_code;

echo '<pre>';
//print_r($line);
echo '</pre>';
}
```

however my html output has an extra radio with value 1 after output the correct value. How can i output the correct value without the `1` showing as a radio button value?

[image]

Comment: Does your file have empty lines after each entry by any chance?

Comment: Yes it does. It has exactly one line break after every entry.

Comment: `1st line \n\n 2nd line \n\n` - that's how the file appears to me. The empty lines thus producing the additional input fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [file()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) instead, as that will load the contents into an array with every line as a separate array item by default.

It also supports a couple of flags that are convenient here, like telling it to skip empty lines:

```
$array = file('brands.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES|FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
```

As you might have guessed, the flag `FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES` will make sure that it skips empty lines.

I also added the flag `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES`. Without that, the linebreaks/new lines at the end of each element will remain.

Comment: I get `1` after every value like Ampex 1, Baofeng 1

Comment: @Gandalf - If you don't want that `1`, remove it from your code: `<span class="badge bg-primary rounded-pill">1</span>`

Comment: Oh dear, that's my fault. I need the one somewhere.

Comment: @Gandalf - If this answer solved your issue, please accept it so others know it has been solved.